# Counting Bloom Filters

Tags: computer-science, data-structure

Suppose I wanted to extend the traditional Bloom Filter to allow deletions and insertions. Using a counting Bloom Filter that has a fixed length ( in my case I want to use 4 bits to keep space small). How can errors arise when using a fixed length of bits? (4 in my case)

Comment: Well, how can errors arise when you only have 4 bits to store a count? What do you do when your count hits 32?

Comment: Ah, that is true. But my next question is how would we bound the probability that an error (going over fixed length of bits count) over the course of x insertions?

Comment: This kinda sounds like homework. What have you tried? What's the probability that a single insertion increments a particular counter?

Comment: Haha not in school anymore. Just doing some reading and trying to understand the idea of a bloom filter better. But to answer your question, I assume the probability is equal for all counters.